# Accessing dictionary in session

Tags: asp.net

Let's say I have a dictionary that I want to store in the session. This dictionary will be storing a list of object with a date as the key.

```
Dictionary<DateTime, List<MyObjects>> SessionDictionaryMyObjects = new...
```

How do I put a list MyList in the dictionary with the key 31/1/2011 and how do I retrieve the list for 1/19/2011 from the dictionary?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
Dictionary<DateTime, List<MyObjects>> SessionDictionaryMyObjects = Session["SessionDictionaryMyObjects"] as Dictionary<DateTime, List<MyObjects>>;
if (SessionDictionaryMyObjects == null)
{
     Session["SessionDictionaryMyObjects"] = SessionDictionaryMyObjects = 
          new Dictionary<DateTime, List<MyObjects>>();
}

// Set value
SessionDictionaryMyObjects.Add(new DateTime(2011, 1, 31), yourListObject);

if (SessionDictionaryMyObjects.Contains(new DateTime(2011, 1, 19)))
{
    // Get value
    List<MyObjects> o = SessionDictionaryMyObjects[new DateTime(2011, 1, 19)];
}
```

You also should sheck if the value exists in the dictionary with `ContainsKey` method

Comment: Lol, declare less variables ;-)

Comment: @Matthew: where can this be reduced in terms of variables?

Comment: `DateTime lookup = new DateTime(2011, 1, 19)` instead of `new DateTime(2011, 1, 19)` multiple times, its unnecessary to declare the same variable with the same value multiple times...

Comment: Oh, found it. SessionDictionaryMyObjects is declared twice %)

Answer (score 1):

```
//to add
List<MyObjects> myList = new List<MyObjects>();
//myList.add("etc") ...

SessionDictionaryMyObjects.Add(DateTime.Parse("31/1/2011"),myList);


//to retrieve    
if (SessionDictionaryMyObjects.ContainsKey(DateTime.Parse("1/19/2011")))
{
 List<MyObjects> myList= SessionDictionaryMyObjects[DateTime.Parse("1/19/2011")];
}
```