# How to assign a dictionary value to a session in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a function that assigns values to a dictionary created in c#.
After some computations in the function, the dictionary is compsed of a value and a key.
I need to create a session save this dictionary in this session.
Can anybody help?

Comment: You mean you want to create a dictionary of sessions? Please elaborate.

Comment: Session itself is a kind of dictionary, too, really - a series of values accessed by key. Are you looking to do something like this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853403/accessing-dictionary-in-session ?

Comment: You can store your dictionary in the Session Dictionary. I think you need to read some about asp.net cache, because store a Dictorionary in a Session, sounds like a chance of cache.

Comment: No the dictionary is compased of string and List<int>. I just need to add this dictianry to a session

Comment: @HanadyDaccache: What dash said is that you also could use the `Session` itself. For example: `Session.Add("Item1",list1);Session.Add("Item2",list2);` and get the items `var list1 = (List<int>)Session["Item1"];`. The only difference is that the session is not strongly typed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put simply, if you have a `Dictionary<string, List<int>>` then putting it in the session is not very complicated;

```
Dictionary<string, List<int>> myDict = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();
HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("MyDictionary", myDict);
```

If you want to check if the Session already contains your dictionary, and only add it if it doesn't then:

```
if(!HttpContext.Current.Session.ContainsKey("MyDictionary"))
{
    HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("MyDictionary", myDict);
}
```

To get it out, remember that it's not typed, `Session` is effectively a dictionary of string, object so you'll have to cast:

```
if(HttpContext.Current.Session.ContainsKey("MyDictionary"))
{
    Dictionary<string, List<int>> myDict = HttpContext.Current.Session["MyDictionary"] as Dictionary<string, List<int>>;
}
```

However, you should also consider what the lifecycle of this object is going to be - Session is not stable in that it has a finite lifetime - it will disappear after a predetermined time of inactivity, for example, so if you want it to hang around for a longer time then you may need to consider alternative strategies.

There's a ton of documentation on Session over at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and it's also a very common topic on Stack Overflow.

Remember also that, as Session is effectively a `Dictionary<String, Object>` managed by the .Net Framework and IIS, you could also do:

```
Session["MyValues"] = new List<Int32>();
```

And, of course, on retrieval:

```
List<Int32> myValues = Session["MyValues"] as List<Int32>();
```

Other alternatives include the Cache; if your object is going to be available to all users of the application then this might be a better solution. Please see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428634/cache-v-s-session) for more information.

I've also voted to close your question as I believe it's too localized, but I hope my answer helps you along the way.